# Is there a symbol to differentiate between dropped call and hanging up normally?

Tags: calls

I have a galaxy s10, long story short I've been dealing with a department that messed up my billing and I'm contesting it, they hung up like 4/5 times and also sent me to voicemail a few times. They're claiming that their system is having issues and that it's dropping calls. I'm wondering if a dropped called has a symbol to identify it? For example this picture here has a bunch of orange arrow going out that says that I called this number, if it was rejected, it would be a blue circle crossed through, if they called me the arrow would be going inwards etc. Does a symbol exists for when a call was dropped on either end? I tried looking this up but I couldn't find an answer about whether this symbol existed or not, just a lot of articles about how to fix dropped calls which isn't an issue I'm having since I can call anybody else just fine

[image]

Comment: How should your phone detect if a computer-system or a human has ended the phone call? On technical level the disconnect command is identical.

Comment: I believe for TCP connections, it's possible to know whether it was a proper disconnection vs a timeout/improper disconnection. For UDP connection though servers can assume an improper disconnection after some specific timeout time has passed or hasn't received some specific data that it needs to receive every x interval. Regardless, it's possible but not too much of this applies to phone calls since they're not using the internet and won't use VoIP, I just wasn't sure if a dropped call and disconnect are marked as two different events or the same. Not familiar with their protocols

Comment: Even if your device makes a VoIP call via VoLTE this does not mean that this is also true for the call center you are calling and you don't have to have a direct VoIP connection. Calls are converted, transmitted and so on. Therefore the connections you see are just between your device and the VoIP server. Therefore even if the VoIP protocol would allow have different messages for signaling a call end those messages have to be implemented and the information on this would have to be sent through all layers and converters and so on.

Comment: Just want to point out that [Android only has 7 standard call types](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CallLog.Calls#TYPE), which don't include an indicator on how the outgoing calls are ended. The most important question though is whether the protocol supported it (as you mentioned), which isn't really an Android question but more to the general telephony service.

Comment: I see, thank you Robert for that explanation. If I understand it right, it means that if something like this were supported, it would still be an issue because both ends would have to support this type of data which is unlikely. And also thank you Andrew, I didn't mean for my question to go in depth but the root of the question ended up being the real question which, yes I agree, is not exactly Android related. Thank you both though